# Error Attempt to de-reference a null object for test class

Tags: unit-test, null

For the method below, I have written test class. But getting error at `fetchInit f = new fetchInit();` inside the method. Error: Attempt to de-reference a null object. How can I avoid this error. Also looking for suggestions if the test class I written is valid for method.

**Fetch Init class**:

```
public class fetchInit{
    public list<case> caseRecord = new list<case>([Select Id, ownerId, status, owner.type
                                    From Case Where ID IN :trigger.new]);        
    Case[] caseQueryUser = New Case[]{};
    Case[] caseQueryQueue = New Case[]{};
}
```

**Method**:

```
public void caseInsert(list<case> caseList){
        fetchInit f = new fetchInit();
        caseList = f.caseRecord;
        if(caseList.size() > 0){
            for(case c : caseList){
                if(c.Status != 'closed'){
                    if(c.owner.type == 'User'){
                        f.caseQueryUser.add(c);
                    } else if (c.owner.type == 'Queue'){
                        f.caseQueryQueue.add(c);
                    }
                }         
            }
            if(f.caseQueryUser.size()>0){postCases_User(JSON.serialize(f.caseQueryUser));}
            if(f.caseQueryQueue.size()>0){postCases_Queue(JSON.serialize(f.caseQueryQueue));}
     }
    }
```

**Test Class**:

```
    public static testmethod void unittest3(){
        caseTriggerPostHandler cls = new caseTriggerPostHandler();
        UtlityCls testHandler = new UtlityCls();        
        contact con = testHandler.createContactRec();
//below line creates 5 cases with user profile as system admin
        list<case> c1 = testHandler.createMultiCaseRec(con, 5);
        cls.caseInsert(c1);
        for(case c : c1){
            system.assertEquals('User', c.owner.type);
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query:

```
public list<case> caseRecord = new list<case>([Select Id, ownerId, status, owner.type From Case Where ID IN :trigger.new]);
```

is referencing `trigger.new`

Yet it is not being executed from a trigger context thus throwing the null reference.

You will need to populate the list of IDs using the constructor or in whatever way suits your needs.

The only way trigger.new will work is if the fetchInit class is always executed from a trigger and nowhere else.

Comment: Thanks Eric.. "You will need to populate the list of IDs using the constructor".. Is it inside test class ?

Comment: No. I do not think you are to the point of writing a test class yet, you need to get the code itself working first....